# What does it mean when the icon next to teammate in spawn menu is flashing?

Tags: battlefield-3

It only happens when they are in a vehicle. It flashes all different colors. Sometimes I am able to join the vehicle. What does this flashing indicate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The icon flashes when the vehicle is under fire/in combat - this is to provide a pre-emptive measure for poor souls who would spawn into a vehicle that is near its end.

Comment: Neither did I - all too often I spawn into an insta-death.